# JavaScript - clearWatch() not triggering on setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering some issues with JavaScript's watchPosition and clearWatch functions that I don't quite understand, would appreciate it if someone could help out.

First off, the function in question...

```
function location(x){
    var getLocation;

    var lat_input = $(x).find(".latitude");
    var lon_input = $(x).find(".longitude");
    var acc_input = $(x).find(".accuracy");

    function showPosition(position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

        $(lat_input).val(latitude);
        $(lon_input).val(longitude);
        $(acc_input).val(accuracy);

        setTimeout(function(){
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(getLocation);
            alert('done');
        }, 10000);  
    };

    getLocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, null, {maximumAge: 0, timeout: Infinity, enableHighAccuracy: true});
};
```

In particular, my problem is with the code in the setTimeout section.

When I run this function on my laptop, everything starts out ok - the .longitude, .latitude, and .accuracy fields are populated accordingly.  After 10 seconds, setTimeout is triggered - I can't say if clearWatch runs successfully (since the computer is pretty limited in its ability to find itself), but the odd behavior that I note here is that `alert('done')` is triggered twice.

When I run this function on my phone (the intended platform), everything gets off to a similarly good start, but after 10 seconds, `alert('done')` starts triggering endlessly, sometimes in immediate succession, sometimes with a few seconds in between.  Most distressing, however, is that clearWatch doesn't appear to run at all - that lat, long, and accuracy fields continuously update after the 10 second mark.

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong here, your guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: try move showPosition outside location function

Comment: You're starting the setTimeout multiple times - every time that function is called, so it will alert even if the watch was cleared after the first 10 seconds.  Perhaps only call setTimeout if you have not done it previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit a similar issue. I found the following code did not stop the watch:

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(locationID);
```

**STEP 1:** Create a variable and assign it to navigator.geolocation

```
var geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;

var geoWatchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(
                onGPSSuccess, onGPSError,
            { maximumAge: 300, timeout: 1500, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

**STEP 2**: Stop Watch use the **var geoloc** not *navigator.geolocation.clearWatch()*

```
geoLoc.clearWatch(geoWatchID);

geoWatchID = null;
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_clearwatch.htm

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the libraries to re-create the code, I can't duplicate the issue so I can only give something to try.

Add a `timer` variable to your outer scope.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(getLocation);
        alert('done');
    }, 10000);
```